# Sphinx Documentation (autodoc) not working after uploading to Github

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have built sphinx documentation for my package.
It is working fine when testing localhost. But after uploading it to `Github` and building docs on `readthedocs.org` the documentation page is not working which uses autodoc.
Here is the link to the Github repository.

https://github.com/SparkDrago05/quick_sqlite

Here is the link to the documentation.

https://quick-sqlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In your [log file](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/17001856.txt), it states `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import class 'QuickSqlite' from module 'quick_sqlite'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'quick_sqlite'`

You need to tell RTD to install your module. See: https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html#making-warnings-more-visible

> The reason `sphinx.ext.autosummary` and `sphinx.ext.autodoc` fail to import the code is because it is not installed. Luckily, the `.readthedocs.yaml` also allows you to specify which requirements to install.
>
> .readthedocs.yaml
>
> ```
> python:
>   # Install our python package before building the docs
>   install:
>     - method: pip
>       path: .
> ```